# Downloading Documents from a password required site

Tags: directory, download, wget

I've learnt about wget and have downloaded a few directories from the web. However, I've hit some roadblocks.

1. I'm trying to download from a site which requires a password and username, which I have access to.
2. There are no apparent directories that I could find from inspecting elements. The site was loading up the documents in a reader.js (whatever that is) and it seemed that each page was being fetched as I clicked the arrow button instead of the whole document.

Any ideas would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

> The site was loading up the documents in a reader.js (whatever that
> is) and it seemed that each page was being fetched as I clicked the
> arrow button instead of the whole document.

This suggest that JavaScript is used to get document, `wget` is not right tool in such situation. You would need another tool, namely one which provides *browser automation*, I suggest giving try PhantomJS (if you are tolerating writing in JavaScript-like language) or selenium (if you are tolerating writing in at least one of officially supported languages).